# How do I redraw something that moves off screen? c#

Tags: c#, console

So I created this 'rectangular graphic' that holds the alphabet. I THOUGHT it would remain at the top of the 'viewable console' (like. . . would scroll down as the user put in more text, etc. I guess the term would be 'floating' header.?

Here's the code for it, as well as the code for the 'alphabet'

```
private static void headerFile()
{
    Console.Clear();
    firstColumn = Console.CursorLeft;
    firstRow = Console.CursorTop;

    int HEADER_HEIGHT = 6;
    int columnNumber = Console.WindowWidth - 1;
    var xcoord = 0;
    var ycoord = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < columnNumber; i++)
    {
        headerWindow("-", i, 0);
        headerWindow("-", i, HEADER_HEIGHT);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < HEADER_HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        headerWindow("|", 0, i);
        headerWindow("|", columnNumber, i);

    }
    headerWindow("+", xcoord = 0, ycoord = 0);
    headerWindow("+", xcoord = columnNumber, ycoord = 0);
    headerWindow("+", xcoord = 0, ycoord = 6);
    headerWindow("+", xcoord = columnNumber, ycoord = 6);
}

private static void letterChoices()
{
    string[] alphabetSelection = File.ReadAllLines("alphabet.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < alphabetSelection.Length; i++)
    {
        //headerWindow("|", 0, 3);

        headerWindow(alphabetSelection[i], i*3+1, 1);
        //Console.Write("\n ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 7);

    }
    //return;
}
```

So is it possible to have a floating 'graphic' that remains at the very top of the console window? OR, is it possible to automatically 're-draw' the same thing when the top of it moves below the viewable area?

And if I have to redraw the rectangle, is there a way to save the screen's state, clear the console, then redraw all progress as if the program was starting fresh, but have all the 'inputs' (such as chosen letters, etc.) remain on screen.

This is 'hangman', btw. Also, please try not to write the code for me - just let me know if it can be done and what things I might need to look at in order to do such a thing. :)

Comment: It's possible...but you'd really be over-complicating things in my opinion.  Just clear the screen, redraw **everything** in the new "state" of the game, then get the next input from the user at the bottom.

Comment: When you say redraw everything, you mean start from scratch? I just want the user to be able to see a constant display of the letters that they have 'guessed' and the letters they haven't without having to scroll up.

Comment: Right...I'd redraw everything, every time.  Clear the screen, then draw the "header" and the hangman.  Down below you can **horizontally** list out all the letters they have/have not used on two different lines.  Finally, down below that, output a prompt and use the standard Console.ReadLine().  The screen wouldn't need to be scrolled ever.

Comment: AHHH. So with every single action, it redraws each time. Now, given that it's a small program, how long do you think it would take with each new redraw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AHHH. So with every single action, it redraws each time. Now, given
>   that it's a small program, how long do you think it would take with
>   each new redraw?

Run this and hit Enter a couple times.

It demonstrates almost the entire screen being re-drawn each time:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while(true)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Top");
        for (int x = 0; x < Console.WindowWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 1; y < Console.WindowHeight - 1; y++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
                Console.Write("X");
            }
        }
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.WindowHeight - 1);
        Console.Write("Prompt: ");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It's not the prettiest, but this is a **console** app.  What were you expecting?...  =)

Comment: While this isn't EXACTLY what I was looking for, it certainly puts my mind in a different set since I know that this kind of thing can be done in this way. In fact, I'm thinking about filling even more of the lines with 'x's' and then removing them to 'show' the hangman. But that seems like it would be a considerable amount of work in order to figure out which positions are what and whether I should use an absolute positioning system or something that is dynamic. I really am not familiar with any of this stuff, but this display you've given is pretty awesome, so thank you!